# Исключения, не понятно откуда, Java

Tags: исключения, java

В общем, при попытке компиляции получаю непонятные мне `exception`'ы и не знаю что с ними делать. Все они отсылаются сначала к некоторым графическим элементам, а потом на создание экземпляров класса `KazemirdoGUI` и `KazemirdoMain`, причём [этих эксепшенов](http://ur1.ca/g8fqa) неимоверное количество. Причём, раньше графика работала и всё отрисовывалось, но теперь - нет.

[Вот вывод из консоли](http://ur1.ca/g8fqa), [вот код с комментариями](http://fpaste.org/63737/13876477/) на те строки, на которые ссылаются исключения.

Подскажите, что делать и что я делаю не так?

Comment: а под отладчиком на какой строке вылетает?

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, т.к. информация по ссылкам больше недоступна.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По порядку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverfЮlowError

Исключение `StackOverflowError` бросается при переполнении стека вызовов. Это должно навести нас на мысль о бесконечной рекурсии.

> ```
> at kazemirdo.KazemirdoMatcher.<init>(KazemirdoMatcher.java:26)
> at kazemirdo.KazemirdoGUI.<init>(KazemirdoGUI.java:17)
> at kazemirdo.KazemirdoMatcher.<init>(KazemirdoMatcher.java:26)
> at kazemirdo.KazemirdoGUI.<init>(KazemirdoGUI.java:17)
> at kazemirdo.KazemirdoMatcher.<init>(KazemirdoMatcher.java:26)
> at kazemirdo.KazemirdoGUI.<init>(KazemirdoGUI.java:17)
> at kazemirdo.KazemirdoMatcher.<init>(KazemirdoMatcher.java:26)
> ```

Становится понятно, что инициализация экземпляра класса `KazemirdoMatcher` становится причиной инициализации экземпляра класса `KazemirdoGUI`. И наоборот. Получается замкнутый круг. Посмотрим, что у нас в строках кода, на которые ссылается стектрейс.

*KazemirdoMatcher.java:26*

```
KazemirdoGUI GUI = new KazemirdoGUI();
```

*KazemirdoGUI.java:17*

```
KazemirdoMatcher kM = new KazemirdoMatcher();
```

Т.е. ваш код непрерывно порождает объекты `KazemirdoGUI` и `KazemirdoMatcher`. Если вы решите этот вопрос - проблем не будет.

Answer (score 3):

ошибка у вас `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError` то есть переполнение стека (советую погуглить на тему stack and heap)

возникает эта ошибка из за зацикливания в создании двух классов

1. kazemirdo.KazemirdoGUI (строка 33)
2. kazemirdo.KazemirdoMatcher (строка 94)

так много ошибок показывает из-за того что разворачивается весь стек (**at** означает **в** чём-то)

у вас получается такое создание классов KazemirdoGUI->KazemirdoMatcher->KazemirdoGUI->KazemirdoMatcher->KazemirdoGUI->KazemirdoMatcher->... (и так до бесконечности)

просто сделайте передачу ссылки в конструкторах или методах

Answer (score 2):

У вас бесконечная рекурсия типа

```
class KazemirdoGUI {
    KazemirdoGUI () {
      new KazemirdoMain();
   }
}
class KazemirdoMain{
    KazemirdoMain() {
      new KazemirdoGUI ();
   }
}
```